# What does the the star or asterisk indicate in Ranger?

Tags: ranger

What does the red star mean in the Ranger file navigator?

[image: Screenshot of directory listing with red star asterisk]

Result of running `ls -la` in same directory:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 philip philip 4096 Oct 18 23:45 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 philip philip 4096 Oct 18 23:36 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 philip philip   82 Oct 18 23:44 john.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 philip philip  114 Oct 18 23:45 john.hpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 philip philip  105 Oct 18 23:09 johnpaul.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 philip philip  136 Oct 18 23:08 johnpaul.hpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 philip philip   82 Oct 18 23:06 paul.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 philip philip  115 Oct 18 23:04 paul.hpp
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Tags

> Tags are single characters which are displayed left of a filename.  You can use tags however you want.  Press <kbd>t</kbd> to toggle tags and <kbd>u</kbd>,<kbd>t</kbd> to remove any tags of the selection. The default tag is an Asterisk (`*`), but you can use any tag by typing `"<tagname>`.

---

*Taken from `LESS='+/TAGS' man ranger`*